# Referring to any of the subclasses of a particular superclass in Java

Tags: java, list, subclass, superclass

Ok guys, here's a simple question that I couldn't quite manage to figure out on my own. Any help is greatly appreciated!

- Let's say I have an abstract class `Superclass`, from which I derived
  subclasses `Subclass1` and `Subclass2`.
- Let's say I have another
  `myClass` class, with a `myField` field. I would like to specify that
  `myField`'s type should be a List of a fixed subclass of `Superclass`, i.e. either
  `List<Subclass1>` or `List<Subclass2>`.

**How should I type `myField`?** `List<Superclass>` doesn't work since such a list could theoretically contain a combination of `Subclass1` *and* `Subclass2` objects... What I'm really looking for here is something like `List<subclass(Superclass)>`. Does that even exist? How would you go about this?

Again, thanks a lot for the help!

Guillaume

Comment: Where would you specify *which* type it is?

Comment: Well if you only want classes of type `Subclass1` you'll have to specify exactly that. Note that `List<Superclass>` wouldn't be correct (except if Superclass could be instantiated itself), it should be `List<? extends Superclass>` if you wanted all subclasses of Superclass - but since that's not what you want, it doesn't really matter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use generics.

```
class MyClass<S extends SuperClass> {
  private List<S> myField;
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Generics are only enforced at compile-time. If he wants the class to accept either so long as they're all the same, he would need runtime checking.

Comment: @jiggy compile-time checking will be sufficient if all code that will run uses generics. Also he wants the list to contain instances of only a single subclass at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [bounded wildcard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html):

```
class MyClass {
    List<? extends Superclass> myField;
}
```

If you do it this way, you cannot call methods such as `add` on `myField` (well, you can, but you can only pass in `null`.

An alternative is a generic class:

```
class MyClass<T extends Superclass> {
    List<T> myField;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you look for is in fact a run time check, what you can do is, declare myField as ,

```
private List<Superclass> myField
```

and have a setter to do the run time validation;

```
public addMyField(Superclass field){

   if (field instanceof Subclass1 || field instanceof Subclass1){
     myField.add(field);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Prabath guidupuy is looking to have instances of only one of those subclasses in his list

Comment: You cannot do it in compile time. It should be a runtime check to fiter out the exact type u need. That's what the answer suggests.

Comment: If you need an exact type of a non-final class then runtime checking is required, but that is not what the original question is about!